# Magento 2 : Filter is not showing in front end in my custom module

Tags: magento2, grid, frontend, filter

i'm creating filter for Frontend in custom module.

I'm following this module grid

https://belvg.com/blog/ui-grid-component-on-the-front-end-in-magento-2.html

But it's not showing in Front end.

**How i can inherit the back end filters Grid to Front end**

and use for my module.

[image]